# Render image from props in react,

Tags: reactjs

I want to receive an image from props. In props, it contains the path of the URL.

For some reason, this does not work.

```
render(){
 const imageURL = require(`${this.props.photo}`)
return (
    <div className="profile">
        <img alt="mug shot" src={imageURL} />
```

but this works....

```
render(){

return (
    <div className="profile">
        <img alt="mug shot" src={require('../../Assets/Photos/Four.png')} />
```

The app was configured using Create-React-App.

Comment: if you use props directly in src then?Like `<img src={this.props.photo} ` />

Comment: That doesn't render, it requires, the require statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please notice that webpack cannot handle dynamic require statements like `` require(`${this.props.photo}`) ``. It can only handle static require statements, as webpack runs in "build time" - it cannot resolve any variables.

Comment: So what is another option I can consider? I have a bunch of images stored in the assets folder. I want each profile to have its own unique image

Comment: Another option will be to receive the image's URL as a prop instead of the actual image file